# Laurent series of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I have 2 functions. I have to express the function in terms of a Laurent series.

The first function is $f(z) = \frac{z^5}{z - 1}$ in the point $z_0 = 1$ for $1 < \parallel z  \parallel < \infty  $.

In this case:
$$
z^5 = (z - 1 + 1)^5 = \sum_{k = 0}^5 \binom{n}{k}(z - 1)^k
$$
so, the problem is solved?

The other function , in the same conditions, is $f(z) = z^5e^{\frac{1}{z}}$. In this case i dont know how to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed solved for $z^5$ (don't forget to divide by the $(z-1)$).

For $z^5e^{z^{-1}}$, find the Taylor expansion of $e^{z^{-1}}$ first, and then multiply with $z^5$.